# Can't send content-type: text/xml header from PHP at the same time getting the data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ajax, header

i hope you can cast some light on my problem. I need to do an AJAX / PHP / MYSQL application to display posts and stuff on the page i'm writing.

I only discovered how to do some simple stuff in PHP after taking some mushrooms but that was years ago and now i don't have mushrooms and i'm just stuck!

So here's the problem:

i think i need to send a proper "xml" file through php so the ajax part can take it but: when i try to put the header on top of the php it displays this error:

" Extra content at the end of the document "

When i looked at some tutorials people were using the "header" fearlesly to do such stuff as i want to do and no comments suggested that it didn't work. so why it doesn't work on my local server?

I'm running:

WAMP
Apache 2.2.11
PHP 5.3.0

It also doesn't work on a remote server (PHP 5.3.0) :/

I read all the stuff i could find till 5am and decided to ask you for help for the first time :)

Thank you!

```
header('content-type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'); 
require_once("allyouneed.php");
require_once("bazingablob.php"); 

$category=$_GET["category"];
$post_tags=$_GET["post_tags"];
$language=$_GET["language"];
$author=$_GET["author"];
$posts_per_page=$_GET["posts_per_page"];
$current_page=$_GET["current_page"];
$order=$_GET["order"];
$hard_limit=$_GET["hard_limit"];
$show_hidden=$_GET["show_hidden"];*/

$wypluj="";
$wypluj="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>";    

$bazinga_blob = new bazingablob;

if (!$bazinga_blob->connect_to_database()) 

        {   
            $wypluj.="<IsOK>0</IsOK>";
            echo $wypluj;
            exit;
        }

        else

        {

            $wypluj.="<IsOK>jedziem</IsOK>";                                        

        }


$bb_result=$bazinga_blob->get_all_posts($category,$post_tags,$language,$author,$posts_per_page,$current_page,$order,$hard_limit,$show_hidden);

if ($bb_result) //udalo sie cos znalezc w bazie wedlug kryteriow

        {

            $wypluj.="<Pagination>";

                $wypluj.="<CurrentPage>";

                $wypluj.=$bazinga_blob->posts_pagination["current_page"];

                $wypluj.="</CurrentPage>";

                $wypluj.="<LastPage>";

                $wypluj.=$bazinga_blob->posts_pagination["last_page"];

                $wypluj.="</LastPage>";

                $wypluj.="<PostsCount>";

                $wypluj.=$bazinga_blob->posts_pagination["posts_count"];

                $wypluj.="</PostsCount>";

            $wypluj.="</Pagination>";


            $wypluj.="<Posts>";


                    foreach ($bb_result as $item) 

                    {

                        $wypluj.="<Post>";

                        $wypluj.="<PostId>".$item->post_id."</PostId>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostAuthor>".$item->post_author."</PostAuthor>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostLangId>".$item->post_langid."</PostLangId>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostSlug>".$item->post_slug."</PostSlug>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostTitle>".$item->post_title."</PostTitle>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostGreetingPicture>".$item->post_greeting_picture."</PostGreetingPicture>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostGreetingVideo>".$item->post_greeting_video."</PostGreetingVideo>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostGreetingSound>".$item->post_greeting_sound."</PostGreetingSound>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostShort>".$item->post_short."</PostShort>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostBody>".$item->post_body."</PostBody>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostDate>".$item->post_date."</PostDate>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostPublished>".$item->post_published."</PostPublished>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostSticky>".$item->post_sticky."</PostSticky>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostComments>".$item->post_comments."</PostComments>";
                        $wypluj.="<PostProtected>".$item->post_protected."</PostProtected>";
                        $wypluj.="</Post>";

                    }

            $wypluj.="</Posts>";



        }


echo $wypluj;
```

Comment: What is giving you the error? PHP? Your browser? Your HTTP client?

Comment: i think it's the php, displaying this message:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 73: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: but the "rendering" doesn't show anything. This error completely disappears if i remove the header section.

Comment: That error message is coming from your browser, not PHP.

Comment: You should be using htmlspecialchars() to convert characters like < into entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from your browser and indicates that your XML is malformed.

Setting the `application/xhtml+xml` header tells the browser to process the document as serious XML. XML needs to be "well-formed", i.e. it **must not** contain any syntax errors. Apparently you do have a syntax error on line 1 at column 73, which makes the browser abort the attempt to process the document.

For this reason it's a pain to hand-code XML, you should really look into a library that takes care of the well-formedness for you, like PHP's own [XMLWriter](http://php.net/xml%20writer).

Comment: deceze, so the line 1 column 73 is about the outputed XML, not the PHP itself?? thanks man

Comment: @Greg Yup. Try to `curl` the document from the command line or use the browsers View Source to look at the raw document.

Comment: here's a simple example of how i go about building an XML DOM which you might find of use http://pastie.org/1237464

Answer (score 1):

Have you validated your XML?
http://friendsofed.infopop.net/4/OpenTopic?a=tpc&s=989094322&f=5283032876&m=4521066061

Comment: Hi, it's me: it was exactly the thing i did wrong: my XML missed a root element for everything i put there - many thanks and good night, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure what you're trying to do with the header, it's not any Ajax method I've ever been taught.  The header method you're doing looks just a few lines short of outputting the XML to a download prompt.

Here's my favorite way to do AJAX.  Simple, understandable, and quick.

1. Include Jquery.
2. Setup your data--whether by form with a Serialize (gets form data into a Javascript Variable) or by just setting some variables as it seems you're doing above.
3. Send via Jquery Ajax to a separate processing page.  The page will receive the data you setup as a $_REQUEST variable, with the method depending on whether you defined it as a POST or not (defaults to a GET)
4. The processing page --does-- stuff with the REQUEST data and may or may not respond back to the page.  This is where you can do stuff like update divs, alert that it worked, etc.

Here's a [great tutorial](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/the-power-of-jquery-with-ajax/).  Focus on the code under "Hello Ajax, Meet Jquery"

If you get yourself any more of those mushrooms, a PHP familiar way to do AJAX is with XAJAX.  It allows you to do asynchronous calls to PHP functions.  Be aware, though, that the forums are not the most english-friendly and documentation is a bit cryptic.

Comment: Hello here, thanks bpeterson76 ! You know it's exactly what i'm doing - i'm using jQuery on the other side of the chain, but the script doesn't work in Internet Explorer so i thought that it is the way i output the xml from php that is wrong

Comment: The method I sent uses JSON most readily...you just run a query and return a JSON string. PHP allows you to send data to the JSON_Encode function, which makes things pretty quick.  You can test online quickly at JSONLint

Comment: cool, JSON sounds good. And thank you everybody, i'll see what i can do with your knowledge, you guys rock. may the peace be with you